# GoogleFit Steps Count return zero after exiting the fragment's parent activity (signout)

Tags: java, android, google-api-client, activity-lifecycle, google-fit

I am working on GoogleFit Api for daily steps count. I am getting the correct result. But when i sign out the application (In this case, app exit the Googlefit fragment's parent activity)
After sign in again, i access the same fragment again, but Googlefit returns the stepsCount as zero and getting times out at result.await.
Here is my Code.
GoogleFitFragment.java

```
package com.example.mudasirrao.mvvm.Fragments.GoogleFitFragments;


import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.mudasirrao.mvvm.R;
import com.example.mudasirrao.mvvm.ViewModel.GoogleFitViewModels.GoogleFitViewModel;
import com.example.mudasirrao.mvvm.databinding.FragmentGoogleFitBinding;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.ConfigApi;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.result.DataTypeResult;

public class GoogleFitFragment extends Fragment {

GoogleFitViewModel googleFitViewModel;

public GoogleFitFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    FragmentGoogleFitBinding fragmentGoogleFitBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_google_fit, container, false);
    View view = fragmentGoogleFitBinding.getRoot();
    googleFitViewModel = new GoogleFitViewModel(getActivity(), fragmentGoogleFitBinding);
    fragmentGoogleFitBinding.setGoogleFitFragmentViewModel(googleFitViewModel);
    return view;

}

}
```

GoogleFitViewModel.java

```
package com.example.mudasirrao.mvvm.ViewModel.GoogleFitViewModels;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.databinding.ObservableField;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.mudasirrao.mvvm.CallBacks.CallBackGoogleFitClient;
import com.example.mudasirrao.mvvm.DataManager.GoogleFitDataManager;
import com.example.mudasirrao.mvvm.databinding.FragmentGoogleFitBinding;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.ConfigApi;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataSet;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Field;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.result.DailyTotalResult;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;


public class GoogleFitViewModel {

private Context context;
private FragmentGoogleFitBinding fragmentGoogleFitBinding;
public final ObservableField<String> steps = new ObservableField<>();
public GoogleApiClient localGoogleApiClient;
String dailySteps;

public GoogleFitViewModel(Context context, final FragmentGoogleFitBinding fragmentGoogleFitBinding) {

    this.context = context;
    this.fragmentGoogleFitBinding = fragmentGoogleFitBinding;
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("dailySteps", MODE_PRIVATE);
    dailySteps = prefs.getString("daily_steps", null);

    if (dailySteps != null) {

        steps.set(dailySteps);
        GoogleFitDataManager.singletonObject(context).buildFitnessClient(new CallBackGoogleFitClient() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {

                localGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
                if (googleApiClient != null) {

                    new VerifyDataTask().execute(localGoogleApiClient);
                    fragmentGoogleFitBinding.setGoalLayout.animate().alpha(0.2f).setDuration(1000);
                    enableDisableLayout(false);
                    fragmentGoogleFitBinding.previewImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    fragmentGoogleFitBinding.saveButton.setText("Edit");
                    fragmentGoogleFitBinding.saveButton.setTag("disabled_edit");
                    fragmentGoogleFitBinding.goalProgressLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fragmentGoogleFitBinding.goalText.setText("Take " + steps.get() + " steps a day");

                }

            }

        });

    } else {

        steps.set("0000");
        fragmentGoogleFitBinding.setGoalLayout.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(3000);

    }

}

public void onClickStepsButton1(View view) {
    steps.set("2000");
}

public void onClickStepsButton2(View view) {
    steps.set("8000");
}

public void onClickStepsButton3(View view) {
    steps.set("10000");
}

public void onClickStepsButton4(View view) {
    steps.set("13000");
}

public void onClickSave(View view) {

    if ((Integer.valueOf(steps.get()) > 0)) {

        if (fragmentGoogleFitBinding.saveButton.getTag() == null) {

            GoogleFitDataManager.singletonObject(context).buildFitnessClient(new CallBackGoogleFitClient() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
                    localGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
                    if (googleApiClient != null) {

                        new VerifyDataTask().execute(localGoogleApiClient);
                        fragmentGoogleFitBinding.setGoalLayout.animate().alpha(0.2f).setDuration(1000);
                        enableDisableLayout(false);
                        fragmentGoogleFitBinding.previewImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        fragmentGoogleFitBinding.saveButton.setText("Edit");
                        fragmentGoogleFitBinding.saveButton.setTag("disabled_edit");
                        fragmentGoogleFitBinding.goalProgressLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }

                }
            });

        } else {

            if (fragmentGoogleFitBinding.saveButton.getTag().equals("disabled_edit")) {

                fragmentGoogleFitBinding.setGoalLayout.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(1000);
                enableDisableLayout(true);
                fragmentGoogleFitBinding.saveButton.setTag("enabled_edit");
                fragmentGoogleFitBinding.saveButton.setText("Save");

            } else if (fragmentGoogleFitBinding.saveButton.getTag().equals("enabled_edit")) {

                new VerifyDataTask().execute(localGoogleApiClient);
                fragmentGoogleFitBinding.setGoalLayout.animate().alpha(0.2f).setDuration(1000);
                enableDisableLayout(false);
                fragmentGoogleFitBinding.saveButton.setText("Edit");
                fragmentGoogleFitBinding.saveButton.setTag("disabled_edit");

            }

        }

        fragmentGoogleFitBinding.goalText.setText("Take " + steps.get() + " steps a day");

    } else

        Toast.makeText(context, "Please Select Steps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

protected void renderStepsProgress(int stepsTaken) {

    saveDailyStepsInSharedPref(steps.get());
    int percentage = (int) (((double) stepsTaken / (double) Integer.valueOf(steps.get())) * 100);
    if (percentage > 100) {
        percentage = 100;
    }
    fragmentGoogleFitBinding.waveLoadingView.setCenterTitle(String.valueOf(percentage) + " %");
    fragmentGoogleFitBinding.waveLoadingView.setProgressValue(percentage);
    fragmentGoogleFitBinding.stepsTakenText.setText("You have taken " + String.valueOf(stepsTaken) + " steps today");

}

private void enableDisableLayout(Boolean visibility) {

    View child;
    for (int i = 0; i < fragmentGoogleFitBinding.stepButtonLayout1.getChildCount(); i++) {

        child = fragmentGoogleFitBinding.stepButtonLayout1.getChildAt(i);
        child.setEnabled(visibility);

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < fragmentGoogleFitBinding.stepButtonLayout2.getChildCount(); i++) {

        child = fragmentGoogleFitBinding.stepButtonLayout2.getChildAt(i);
        child.setEnabled(visibility);

    }

}

private void saveDailyStepsInSharedPref(String dailySteps) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("dailySteps", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("daily_steps", dailySteps);
    editor.apply();
}

private class VerifyDataTask extends AsyncTask<GoogleApiClient, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(GoogleApiClient... params) {


        int total = 0;

        PendingResult<DailyTotalResult> result = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal(params[0], DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);
        DailyTotalResult totalResult = result.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (totalResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

            DataSet totalSet = totalResult.getTotal();
            total = totalSet.isEmpty()
                    ? 0
                    : totalSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt();

        } else {

            Log.d("steps_count_error", "There was a problem getting the step count!!");

        }

        return total;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

        renderStepsProgress(result);

    }

}

}
```

GoogleFitDataManager.java

```
package com.example.mudasirrao.mvvm.DataManager;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.mudasirrao.mvvm.CallBacks.CallBackGoogleFitClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.FitnessStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType;

import static com.bumptech.glide.gifdecoder.GifHeaderParser.TAG;


public class GoogleFitDataManager {

    private static GoogleFitDataManager googleFitDataManager;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = null;
    private Context context;

    public GoogleFitDataManager(Context context) {

        this.context = context;

    }

    public static GoogleFitDataManager singletonObject(Context context) {

        if (googleFitDataManager == null) {

            googleFitDataManager = new GoogleFitDataManager(context);

        }

        return googleFitDataManager;
    }

    public void buildFitnessClient(final CallBackGoogleFitClient callBackGoogleFitClient) {

        if (googleApiClient == null) {

            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                    .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
                    .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
                    .addApi(Fitness.CONFIG_API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                                                    subscribeGoogleFit(googleApiClient);
                                                    callBackGoogleFitClient.onResponse(googleApiClient);

                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

                                                    if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {

                                                        Toast.makeText(context, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                    } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {

                                                        Toast.makeText(context, "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                    )
                    .enableAutoManage((FragmentActivity) context, 0, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

                            Log.i("TAG", "Google Play services connection failed. Cause: " + result.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Exception while connecting to Google Play services: " + result.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    })
                    .build();

        } else {
            subscribeGoogleFit(googleApiClient);
            callBackGoogleFitClient.onResponse(googleApiClient);
        }

    }

    public void subscribeGoogleFit(GoogleApiClient client) {

        Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(client, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {

                        if (status.isSuccess()) {

                            if (status.getStatusCode() == FitnessStatusCodes.SUCCESS_ALREADY_SUBSCRIBED) {

                                Log.i(TAG, "Existing subscription for activity detected.");

                            } else {

                                Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed!");

                            }
                        } else {

                            Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem subscribing.");

                        }

                    }
                });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was doing that I was creating the static object of the class in which I was making the googlefit client. In this case, when I exit the Activity, the object was not destroying and googlefit client was getting disconnected due to the enableAutoManage in onDestroy of the fragment. And as per my checks, I was not connecting to the googleFit client again.

I removed the object as static and now I stick the API client class object with the life cycle of the activity in which my fragment resides. Also I removed enableAutoManage and now connecting and disconnecting the API client by myself.